# Getting C# Int64 in Python

Tags: c#, python, types, long-integer, int64

I have to get an Int64 object in Python. My code looks like this:

```
from System import Int64
l = Int64.Parse('123')
print(l, type(l))
```

but it returns: `123 <class 'int'>`

When I did the same with DateTime c# object, it returned just right type: `<class 'System.DateTime'>`

So why does Python convert an Int64 C# object back to it's own int class?

I need exactly this type, because I'm sending it to external program, which otherwise fails.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure if there exists int64 in native python. Maybe you want to use numpy??

Comment: `long` (`Int64`) is a primitive; I would *expect* python to map that to its own closest primitive... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way, but it's quite a harakiri:

```
Int64.__new__(Int64, value)
```